# Merge unknown number of paralell subtasks to one Completable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I need to create concurrent network requests. Depending on the result of these requests, more requests might be started.

I want to get a single Completable that completes once all of the requests have finished and no further request need to be created.

My question is, is this possible to achieve using the following snippet:

```
return Completable.defer(() -> {
        startRequests();
        return Observable.merge(requestSubject.asObservable()).toCompletable();
    });
```

In this example, startRequest would add network requests (Retrofit) to the requestSubject, which is a `PublishSubject<Observable<SomeResponse>>`.

Specifically I'd expect the network requests to start on the IO scheduler once subscribed, and the returned Completable to not complete until I, in the onNext of one of the requests, call `requestSubject.onComplete()`.

I have yet to figure out how I will process the response of the requests without executing the request twice (Retrofit requests on each subscribe).

Does it work this way, or is there a better way to achieve what I am looking for? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a full code? Because I don't see any point in deferring and in merging a single subject.
Please also post `startRequests()` code.

Comment: @Dimezis It's a loop that creates and publishes (the first round of parallel) network requests using `requestSubject.onNext(client.createRequest(parameter));`. I think you are right, since creating those requests does not execute them, I could just create them on the calling thread and return the Completable that starts them on subscription. The example I posted would not have worked with a PublishSubject anyway, I think it would have needed a ReplaySubject.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `flatmap()` and convert it to `Completable`.

Here is an example that is (simulating) executing network request which returns 2 items on `io` pool then it performs computation on these items in `computation` pool, everything parallel:

```
@Test
public void foo() throws Exception {
    Observable.range(1, 10)
            .flatMap(this::getNItemsFromNetwork)
            .flatMap(this::asyncCompuatation)
            .ignoreElements()
            .subscribe(() -> System.out.println("onComplete"),
                    (t) -> System.out.println("onError"));

    Thread.sleep(10000);
}

Observable<String> getNItemsFromNetwork(int count) {
    return Observable.just(count)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Executing request for " + count + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread()))
            .flatMap(number -> Observable.just("Item nr " + number + ".1", "Item nr " + number + ".2"))
            .delay(random.nextInt(1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

Observable<String> asyncCompuatation(String string) {
    return Observable.just(string)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .delay(random.nextInt(1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Computing " + number + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread()));
}
```

And output for validation:

`Executing request for 7 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-7,5,main]
Executing request for 6 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-6,5,main]
Executing request for 5 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-5,5,main]
Executing request for 1 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
Executing request for 4 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-4,5,main]
Executing request for 3 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-3,5,main]
Executing request for 8 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-8,5,main]
Executing request for 2 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-2,5,main]
Executing request for 9 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-9,5,main]
Executing request for 10 on thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-10,5,main]
Computing Item nr 7.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
Computing Item nr 10.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
Computing Item nr 6.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
Computing Item nr 3.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
Computing Item nr 4.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
Computing Item nr 3.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
Computing Item nr 6.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
Computing Item nr 2.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
Computing Item nr 5.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
Computing Item nr 5.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
Computing Item nr 7.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
Computing Item nr 2.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
Computing Item nr 10.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
Computing Item nr 9.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
Computing Item nr 4.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
Computing Item nr 9.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
Computing Item nr 8.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-5,5,main]
Computing Item nr 8.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-2,5,main]
Computing Item nr 1.1 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-7,5,main]
Computing Item nr 1.2 on thread: Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-1,5,main]
onComplete`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure if I got your question 100% correct, but here's a rough sketch of what I would do... I believe you want to have a `Subject` as an intermediate level for caching and not interrupting actual request when you will call unsubscribe.

1) Assume you have 2 Retrofit Observables.

2) In `startRequests()` you need to subscribe to both of them (on some scheduler you need), apply `doOnNext` operator and delegate data to your `subject`. So the subject will receive 2 ticks of data from API.

3) Subscribe to your subject, you will receive 2 ticks of data.

Basically there's no need to wait for completion, you will just receive N amount of onNext ticks.
But if you want to have some indicator that all of the requests have completed, you can for example merge all retrofit observables, and delegate all events to subject, so it will receive N amount of onNext ticks and onComplete in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `Subjects`, are unnecessary complication. 
You can simply use `flatMap()` and transfer to `Completable` at the end using `toCompletable()`, you didn't mention how does your specific loop works, but assuming you have some List that you loop queries upon it goes something like this, where `startRequest(data)` returns your `Retrofit` query `Observable`:

```
 List<Data> list = ...;
    Observable.from(list)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Data, Observable<Result>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Result> call(Data data) {
                    return startRequest(data);
                }
            }).toCompletable();
```

regarding your second request, of doing more requests depends on the result, in this case you might want to gather all requests using `toList()`, you will get one `onNext()` notification, then you can filter it all, and get `Observable` that emit item when you want to request more data :

```
 List<Data> list =...;
    Observable.from(list)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Data, Observable<Result>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Result> call(Data data) {
                    return startRequest(data);
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .filter(new Func1<List<Result>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<Result> results) {
                    return shouldRequestMore(results);
                }
            });
```